# Problems with moderation tool for a comments box

Tags: comments, facebook-apps

I'm already some nights working to get the moderation tool working for a comment box on different pages. On this site and on the net I can't find a answer that solves my problem.

If I put the link of my site in the debug tool I get the following:

> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>   Object Invalid Value:
>   Object at URL 'http://www.mysite.be/Page.php' of type 'website' is >invalid because the given value '{e-mail@msn.com}' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed >as type 'fbid'.

So I checked if my user id is correct. It is, but in my code, in the head, it is a number:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="5897144XX"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="3226088511525XX"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.be/page.php" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Discription" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.be/page.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="150" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="150" />
```

Above the head I put:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
```

In the body:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.mysite.be/page.php" data-num-posts="5" data-width="470"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src= "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=3226088511525xx"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '3226088511525xx', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.mysite.be/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

The commentbox works fine and people can give reactions on an article and it shows on facebook. But the reactions I don't see in the moderation tool.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have an additional `og:tag` hiding somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because its the first time I used this. But to be really sure I checked and I didn't find others.
Maybe it is also interristing that I use addthis on my site.

Comment: Hi, I had two times meta tags (app_id and admin_id) placed in the code of the workingfile. That was the problem (wrong id in one of the codes).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, Facebook has debug tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

While it's not 100% bullet proof (eg, once I had a problem with an image, which worked fine in debug tool but was not visible on the url submission), but may find subtle errors in the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

U cant have admins and app id as meta tag at the same time. You have to remove one, if i were you i should chose ur own user profile to delete